# How to rewrite "It's possible that it's correct" into a sentence that starts with "That...?"

Tags: meaning, sentence

I'm thinking about "That could be correct" or "That is possibly correct"—although I'm not sure if any of the sentences above are valid.

Comment: Why do you feel they aren't valid?

Comment: I don't like "is" as well here, because "is" doesn't sound as doubtful. // I think you might be happier asking this type of question over on English Language Learners.

Answer (score -2):

Your sentence can be rewritten as:

> That this is correct is possible.

or

> That it is correct is possible.

Comment: That that that is used correctly is possible.

Comment: I think this must be what is required, though it's horribly stilted. Your proposed answers with "that" for "it" are not rewriting the sentence: they're producing a sentence of similar meaning.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include a source?

Comment: Try to get in the habit of providing documentation in an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You could say "That may be correct".

Comment: Try to get in the habit of providing documentation in an answer.  (Otherwise, you do have enough rep to leave a comment....)

Comment: I was responding to the inquiry. I don't understand what happened to every participant on this page.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what your second comment sentence means exactly, but I sense some sort of confusion on your part.  Let me try again.  Your answer has been downvoted twice, and has not been upvoted.  I want to acknowledge your willingness to help the person who asked the question!  But I also want to provide some guidance that will help you write more successful answers (i.e. that will fare better in voting).  My suggestion is to provide more documentation for your answers, in future....  Hope that is clearer than my first comment!

Comment: Never mind. I now understand that it is common for double down votes to sweep broadly across a page here.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're right not to take it personally.  But the site gets a lot of traffic, so there is a concerted effort to keep the standards high.  When this was explained to me, the people who explained were harsh about it, so I tried to let you know in what I hoped was a less hurtful way.

Comment: It's a troubling pattern. I now know, and others before me have recognized, that on this site that the first 2 down votes should be treated like a glitch caused by vandals who really don't want the posts to be voted up or down by the community at large, but rather feel entitled to put their thumb on the scale. No problem. Now I know.

Comment: That was not the case in this situation.  I will tell you how I know.  I have enough rep to be able to see the upvotes and the downvotes, not just the net number.  There are 0 upvotes for this answer, and two downvotes, one of which was cast by me.  The other downvoter did not leave a comment explaining his downvote, but I did. I will try again to explain: answers that are extremely brief, with no documentation or explanation, tend to get downvoted on this site, as an attempt to encourage participants to write well though out answers.  It's not enough to think the answer through thoroughly...

Comment: ...in your own mind.  To write a helpful, high quality answer, one must also provide documentation. // I consider myself part of the community here. // If you ever see me or anyone else posting a comment that looks like vandalism, please flag it for moderator attention.